# Регулярное выражение или вытащить баланс без USD

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо вытащить со страницы баланс без USD, вот её кусок кода данной страницы:

```
<div class="rbox-wrap">
        <div class="rbox-heading">
            <h4 class="">Портфолио</h4>
        </div>
<div class="rbox-content">
    <table class="half-1">
        <tr><td>Количество открытых ставок</td><td id="nop">: <strong>0</strong></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Баланс вашего счета</td><td id="ac">: <strong class="balance">USD 5,418.39</strong></td></tr>
    </table>

preg_match( '/<strong class="balance">([\s\S]*?)<\/strong>/is' , $content , $links );
```

вытаскивает только целиком USD 5,418.39  а мне нужно 5,418.39

SOS!!!!

Comment: Как костыль можно попробовать обработать результат str_replace('USD', '', $subj);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение

```
(?<=USD )(\d{1,3}[,])*\d{1,3}(\.\d{2})?
```

Выхватит суммы из таких случаев:

- USD 5,418.39
- USD 534.23
- USD 5
- USD 0.99
- USD 8,345,545.00

Здесь не пример кода, а множество возможных вариантов было бы полезно.

Comment: Тогда уж так:  

    (?<=USD )\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?
Чтобы исключить числа вроде:

    1,2,34,5

Comment: @ReinRaus, классное уточнение.